# MySQL query works but PHP returning Exception: errorinfo:null

Tags: php, mysql, exception, pdo, sql-update

The following code updates the table correctly, but it also returns an Exception. Any idea what might be happening here?

```php
public function updateThis($aaa){
try
{
    $success = false;

    $query = "
        UPDATE this_table
        SET thing = '0'
        WHERE aaa = :aaa";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    $stmt->bindParam(':aaa', $aaa);

    $stmt->execute();

    if($this->conn->commit())
        $success = true;

    return $success;
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    return $e;
}
}
```

Comment: What does `$e->getMessage()` say?

Comment: @drew010 It says "drew010 is a legend, give the man a point.."
 Actually, it said "There is no active transaction" to which I went back and added `$this->conn->beginTransaction();` it now works..

Comment: Do I even need a transaction for this one row update?

Comment: @rideTheWave Probably not, unless is happens to be an exceptionally long single row update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using PDO, Auto-Commit is on by default, unless you specifically turn it off using [Begin Transaction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php). I can't see it in your connection, so are you perhaps trying to commit a transaction that has already been auto-commited?